# When I compiled Java code using Gradle plug-ins, the local JDK was 1.8, but I wanted to compile it into version 1.7

Tags: java, gradle

When I compiled Java code using Gradle plug-ins, the local JDK was 1.8, but I wanted to compile it into version 1.7. Error: javacTask: Source Release 1.8 Requires Target Release 1.8

- gradle 5.5.1
- jdk 1.8

```
17:56:11.435 [ERROR] [system.err] javacTask: 源发行版 1.8 需要目标发行版 1.8
17:56:11.435 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Compile Java for :compileJava'
17:56:11.435 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Compile Java for :compileJava' completed
17:56:11.435 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute compile for :compileJava'
17:56:11.435 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute compile for :compileJava' completed
17:56:11.436 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.TaskFingerprintUtil] Fingerprinting property destinationDir (Output) for task ':compileJava'
17:56:11.436 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep] Not storing result of task ':compileJava' in cache because the execution failed
17:56:11.436 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
17:56:11.436 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Task :compileJava'
17:56:11.437 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :compileJava' completed
17:56:11.437 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] :compileJava (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 1.544 secs.
17:56:11.437 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker for ':': released lock on :
17:56:11.437 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.2 completed (1 worker(s) in use)
17:56:11.438 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker for ':': released lock on root.1.2
17:56:11.438 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] Execution worker [Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 1.546 secs
17:56:11.438 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] Execution worker [Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 1.545 secs
17:56:11.438 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] Execution worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle: 1.545 secs
17:56:11.438 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] Execution worker [Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]] finished, busy: 1.544 secs, idle: 0.002 secs
17:56:11.438 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph] Timing: Executing the DAG took 1.548 secs
17:56:11.439 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run tasks'
17:56:11.439 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Run tasks' completed
17:56:11.440 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
17:56:11.441 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 4: released lock on root.1
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
17:56:11.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
17:56:11.442 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Comment: Why do you want to compile it to 1.7, given that it is end of life?

Comment: @JoeC if only end of life meant that everybody had upgraded to a supported version... ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The source release property specifies what language version the source code is written in (java files), the target release specifies what runtime version to target for class files. You probably forgot to specify `sourceCompatibility = '1.7'` in the `compileJava` block.